# Adobe DTM - set a success event in the Adobe Analytics tool ONLY IF a discrete data element value exists

Tags: events, adobe, analytics, element, tms

I'm curious if there's a way to set a success event in the Adobe Analytics tool [without using the Custom Script option], ONLY IF a discrete data element value exists.

For example, I have a data layer object that captures a value in one of two flavors: value1 and value2. The data layer object looks something like this:

```
'data_capture': 'value1|value2'
```

In Adobe DTM, I set a Data Element named data_capture

```
return data_layer.data_capture
```

I'm using a direct call rule [Ajax screen] to activate my Adobe Analytics tool and fire event1, only if %data_capture% has a value of 'value1'.

Just to reiterate, if %data_capture% = 'value1', set event1=%data_capture%. if %data_capture% is not = 'value1', do not set event1.

I'm not a programmer, so my apologies if any of the syntax is jacked-up. Any thoughts on a solution would be greatly appreciated.

Art -- [linkedin.com/in/arthurlwebb](http://linkedin.com/in/arthurlwebb) | [twitter.com/arthurlwebb](http://twitter.com/arthurlwebb)

Answer (score 1):

For Event base rules and page load rules there is such option,
please check: rule / condition / criteria 
in select box(criteria)  there is 'chapter' data and there is option data element value. When added, user is able to choose data element from list and set condition value.

Unfortunately there is no such option for direct call rules.